# How is the distinction between discrete and continuous materialized in the brain

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, brain, mathematical-ability

It's generally admitted that some things are continuous (e.g. quantity of water, the length of a stick) whereas some other are not (how many oranges do I have in my bag?).

In mathematics, discrete sets are "finite or countable" whereas the continuum generally refers to things that are at least as large as the real numbers.

My question is, what is the common view on how these two concepts emerge in the brain? Are there specific processing for "continuous" data and discrete data?